# What's the correct syntax to select individual elements?

Tags: jquery

In this instance when I hover over any of the columns all of the `.p1` elements in the page fade in. How can I have only the element I'm currently hovering over to fade in and not the rest?

```
$('.column1, .column2, .column3, .column4, .column5').mouseenter(function() {
    $(".p1").fadeIn(200);
    $(this).animate({
        height: '100%'
    });
});


$('.column1, .column2, .column3, .column4, .column5').mouseleave(function() {
    $(".p1").fadeOut(200);
    $(this).animate({
        height: '100px',
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `this` keyword to reference the element that triggered the event, like this:

```
$('.column1, .column2, .column3, .column4, .column5').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).fadeIn(200).animate({
       height: '100%'
    });
});

$('.column1, .column2, .column3, .column4, .column5').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(200).animate({
        height: '100px'
    }); 
});
```

Also note that you can shorten the code by using a common class on all the elements, using the `hover()` handler and `fadeToggle()`. Try this:

```
$('.column').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeToggle(200).animate({
        height: $(this).height() == 100 ? '100%' : '100px'
    }); 
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I don't want the whole element to fade In and out, just the text inside, so just the ".p1" class elements, but the columns should be visible.

Comment: Please add your HTML to the question. Please note that you can only animate elements, not text nodes so you may need to change your HTML.

Comment: Basically, with my original code, if I only had 1 column, it works perfectly fine, I hover over the column, it raises up because of the animate, and the text fades in and out, but yea of course it triggers all .p1 elements and that's what i want to prevent.